# Show that a given function exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, numerical-methods

Consider a sequence $x_{k + 1} = f(x_{k})$, where $f \in C^{3}$. Moreover, assume $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$. Show that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that

$$|x_{k+1}| \leq g(x_{k})|x_{k}|^{3}.$$

---

I tried rewriting it as a function in $f$, but I didn't get anywhere. I got

$$|f(x_{k})|/|x_{k}|^{3} \leq g(x_{k}), $$

from which I have been stuck. I'm guessing that you need to use the fact that $f^{(n)} = 0$ for $n = 1, 2$ since they wouldn't have given it to us otherwise?

Comment: What properties must $g$ satisfy?

Comment: Continuity. Sorry, I didn't mention that. Let me update it.

Comment: If the first three derivatives are $0$ you can define $g(x)=\frac {f(x)} {x^{3}}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $\frac 1 6 f^{'''} (0)$ for $x=0$. There might have been a misprint.

Comment: The book defined $g(x) = f'''(z_{x})/6$. Do you know what $z_{x}$ is? Or, how they got this answer?

Comment: If $f^{(n)}=0$ was not given for $n=1,2$, you could use $f(x)=x$. In this case $|f(x_k)|/|x_k|^3$ is not bounded for $x\to 0$, so the function $g$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: Sorry, $f^{(n)} = 0$ is given for $n = 1, 2$. Also, $f(0) = 0$

Comment: @stackofhay42 In the book, they probably apply Taylor-Lagrange formula at the order $2$ between $0$ and $x_k$. This gives you that for all $x$, there exists $z_x$ such that $f(x)=x^3 \times f'''(z_x)/6$. But the continuity of such a $g$, without saying anything more, is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define 
$$g(x) = \left|\frac{f(x)}{x^3}\right| \text{ if } x\neq 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad g(0)=\frac{f'''(0)}{6}$$

Obviously, you get for all $k$ that
$$|x_{k+1}| = g(x_k) |x_k|^3$$

Now you have to prove that $g$ is continuous. It is the case on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ ; moreover, Taylor Lagrange formula between $0$ and $x$ shows that for all $x$, there exists $z_x \in [0,x]$ such that
$$f(x)=x^3\frac{f'''(z_x)}{6}$$

So for all $x \neq 0$, 
$$|g(x)-g(0)|=\left|\frac{f'''(z_x)-f'''(0)}{6}\right|$$

which tends to $0$, because $z_x$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$, and $f'''$ is continuous.

This shows that $g$ is continuous also in $0$.